# If Substance A is more soluble in water than Substance B, will Substance A be more easily absorbed by the body?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, solubility, carbohydrates

I am comparing the solubilities of artificial vs natural sweeteners for my Chemistry IB Internal Assessment. I must demonstrate personal engagement, so I am relating my topic to weight management in which I am saying that if a sweetener is more soluble in water, then it will be more easily absorbed by the body. Ergo, since the body's need for carbohydrates has been satiated, one will feel less need to eat sugar, thus aiding in weight loss.

I'm not quite sure if the above is true, so I would be very open to any suggestions or corrections. Please indicate any reference material in your answers to my question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Slightly related: [How do water insoluble medications get absorbed in the blood stream?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/how-do-water-insoluble-medications-get-absorbed-in-the-blood-stream/37963#37963)

Comment: If by 'easily absorbed' you mean quickly then I would guess that it would, since it takes time to dissolve. How big that difference is will clearly depends on the substance.

Comment: Of course, if water soluble, it also goes out easily...

Comment: Absorption of nutrients on the body does not relate directly to solubility, there are many factors to consider (e.g. fats in milk) and the other ingredients greatly affect this (e.g. iron in meat vs. iron in vegetables). Also, carbohydrates have different effects on appetite depending on the particular molecule; common sugar gives you calories but doesn't really kill your hunger, while fiber isn't absorbed by your body but it certainly satiates it.